# reviewing commited but unpushed changes in the remote branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

I checked out a branch (remotebranch) from git repository in a local branch (localbranch):

```
git checkout -b localbranch origin/remotebranch
```

How can someone with the access to the same git repository access commited and unpushed changes in the "localbranch" from a remote machine?

Thank you in advance

Comment: only if he has access to your machine

Answer (score 0):

People who want to see the changes committed into your local `localbranch` branch (and not yet pushed to the original repository) needs some kind of access to your machine to be able of cloning your local repository and see such commits.

This means that the repository containing `localbranch` needs to be online or at least accessible through SSH or through the Git daemon. The set-up could be hard in case you are behind a NAT or a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could share the changes with another user without pushing to the `remotebranch` on `origin`.

When you say "not pushed", that may mean only that you don't want to update the `remotebranch` on `origin` yet, or you might specifically not want these commits to be visible on `origin`; so that would affect your options.

The simplest (and I would say most typical) thing to do is just create a different branch on the `origin`.  Normally if you knew you'd do this when you created `localbranch` you might start slightly differently, like

```
git checkout remotebranch
```

to create a local branch tracking `origin/remotebranch`, and then

```
git checkout -b localbranch
```

You can then push `localbranch` to `origin/localbranch` without affecting `remotebranch`.  (Even though you created `localbranch` from `origin/remotebranch` you can still make this work as long as you set up tracking properly or use the correct refspecs.)

Later you can merge `localbranch` bakc to `remotebranch` (possibly using fast-forward if nobody else has modified `remotebranch`).

But again, that's only workable if you're willing to put the commits on the origin.  If you want to share the commits *only* with the person who will review them, then you still have a couple options.

As Claudio suggests, you could have your collaborator add your local repo as a remote to their local repo.  This is dependent on your repo being accessible from their computer using a protocol git understands; and it requires you to be online when they fetch your work.

You can get around those problems by creating a bundle containing your local changes.

```
git bundle create my_changes.bundle origin/remotebranch..localbranch
```

Then you send (email, ftp, whatever) `my_changes.bundle` to your collaborator, who can treat it like a read-only remote

```
git remote add bundle /local/path/to/my_changes.bundle
```